# Rails: Jquery/Javascript fails to load from correct assets location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with my Jquery and Javascript.  I've been building an application, using github to work on it between work and at home.  At work, everything works fine, all of my Jquery works.  When I pull the app at home, the jquery and javascript does not respond.  This includes the javascript I'm using from bootstrap.

The browsers' javascript console is showing some errors that seem to be the root of the problem but I'm not sure how to go about fixing them.

My application layout include this:

```
<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <title>Website</title>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
   ...
   <body>
   ...
   <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
```

and my application.js has this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap.min.js
```

What else should I check or try to change?

My browser javascript console throws some errors as well:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/requests/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/requests/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

requests is one of my models.  Depending on which mvc I'm currently working with, it will search for the resources in those folders. For example when I try to use the javascript that's in my "ecn" view, I get the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/ecns/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/ecns/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Why would rails be trying to look for the assets in any folder other than the assets folder?

Comment: Are there errors in the browser’s JavaScript console?

Comment: What does "not respond" mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the browser's Javascript console.  And by not respond, If I have a button to open a modal, when I click the button, the browser "twitches", nothing happens, but the window jumps back to the top

Comment: scratch that, I found the console and it does have errors: I added them above

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the line `<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` in your application layout because your `application.js` already include `bootstrap.min.js` ( exactly this line : `//= require bootstrap.min.js` ), so don't need to include it twice, the same thing for this line `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` you should remove it.

Second thing is errors you are getting from console :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://localhost:3000/requests/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/requests/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

it seem that your app try to load `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.css` from a folder called `requests/js` and `requests/css`, have you already such folders ? 
i think bootstrap generator will use the `/app/assets` directory if you are using Rails >= 3 exactly `app/assets/javascripts/` and `app/assets/stylesheets/`

I think this railscast [Twitter Bootstrap Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast) can help you too

Comment: Yes, I noticed it's looking in folders that do not exist.  "requests" is a table I recently generated using the scaffold generator, but all of my stylesheets and js are in the assets folder.

Comment: try to remove also this line : <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> , i think it have no sense

Comment: @sabrams i think you get these errors because of the two lines i noticed in my answer, try to remove them then see if the error still the same

Comment: That has no effect.  I have noticed that depending on what view I have open on my application, the javascript error looks into that folder: `GET http://localhost:3000/ecns/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)`
`GET http://localhost:3000/requests/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)`
What would cause it to look in these folders rather than the assets folder?

Comment: no idea :( but is you who added this line //= require bootstrap.min.js in your application.js file ? try to remove this line too, if nothing happens try to place it before //= require_tree .

Comment: Yeah, I added it, and I tried moving and deleting it to no prevail.  Thanks for the help though.